# Timer act only if i touch the display (OnTouchListener)

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

The Timer works fine. The problem is that the method _dw.newgame() just get executed(if two seconds are over) if i touch the display. Maybe it have sth to do with the "OnTouchListener" ?

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener{
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

public DrawView(Context context)
{
timer.schedule(new Task(this),0, 2000);
}
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{}
}

class Task extends TimerTask
{
private DrawView _dw; 
public Task(DrawView dw){ this._dw = dw;}
public void run()
{ _dw.newgame(); }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should start the timer in the `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new Task(this), 0, 2000);
}
```

second try with handler:

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener{
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage();
            }
        }, 0, 2000);
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            newgame();
        }
    };
}
```

I did not compile this but it should work like this.
I noticed another thing: I suppose newgame() should only be called once.

```
timer.schedule(new Task(this), 0, 2000);
```

does that every 2 secs.

Comment: Thank you i thought thats it but its not :( its the same like before

Comment: If newgame() changes something at the gui you may use a handler for that. I can give you an example if you need one.

Comment: Aaahh okay. That sounds clear. An example would be really cool.